# run test after specified amount of time

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, junit5

I want to create integration tests for my project using JUnit 5 (I know, it's mainly for Unit Tests).

The problem is that I want to test an error message that occurs only if a certain time limit is reached.

Is it possible to let other tests run and let the test fail if the condition is invalid after a specified timeout?

Basically, I want something like this:

```
assertAfter(time,()->assertWhatever());
```

or

```
assertTrueAfter(time,()->myTest());
```

Comment: I wonder why `Thread.sleep` wasn't considered yet

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: I want to run other tests during that time but there are tests that cannot run in parallel.